# Is ScreenManager compatible with DropDown in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to generate a dropdown-list in my second screen managed by Kivys ScreenManager. If I do so, I get this traceback:

```
    ... 
File "C:/Users/ORANG/PycharmProjects/waldi/playground/cw.py", line 76, in on_text
         instance.drop_down.open(instance)
File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\kivy27\kivy\uix\dropdown.py", line 215, in open
         'Cannot open a dropdown list on a hidden widget')
     kivy.uix.dropdown.DropDownException: Cannot open a dropdown list on a hidden widget
```

This is the code, which is basically the same as in this 
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193494/kivy-clear-widget-strange-behaviour-reproducible-code-attached), just embedded in a screenmanager scenario simple as can be:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
import re
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Lieferant>:
    ComboLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Label'
        ComboEdit:
            size_hint: .5, .3
            pos_hint: {'center':(.5, .5)}
            # `args` is the keyword for arguments passed to `on_text` in kv language
            on_text: self.parent.on_text(self, args[1])
''')

class ComboEdit(TextInput):
    """
    This class defines a Editable Combo-Box in the traditional sense
    that shows it's options
    """
    options = ListProperty(('',))
    '''
    :data:`options` defines the list of options that will be displayed when
    touch is released from this widget.
    '''

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        ddn = self.drop_down = DropDown()
        ddn.bind(on_select=self.on_select)
        super(ComboEdit, self).__init__(**kw)

    def on_options(self, instance, value):
        ddn = self.drop_down
        # clear old options
        ddn.clear_widgets()
        for option in value:
            # create a button for each option
            but = Button(text=option,
                         size_hint_y=None,
                         height='36sp',
                         # and make sure the press of the button calls select
                         # will results in calling `self.on_select`
                         on_release=lambda btn: ddn.select(btn.text))
            ddn.add_widget(but)

    def on_select(self, instance, value):
        # on selection of Drop down Item... do what you want here
        # update text of selection to the edit box
        self.text = value

class ComboLayout(BoxLayout):
    rtsstr = StringProperty("".join(("Substrate1,,,Substrate1,,,Substrate1,,,",
                                     "Substrate1,,,Substrate1,,,Substrate_coating",
                                     ",,,silicon,,,silicon_Substrate,,,substrate_",
                                     "silicon,,,")))
    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        if value == '':
            instance.options = []
        else:
            match = re.findall("(?<=,{3})(?:(?!,{3}).)*?%s.*?(?=,{3})" % value, \
                               self.rtsstr, re.IGNORECASE)
            # using a set to remove duplicates, if any.
            instance.options = list(set(match))
        instance.drop_down.open(instance)
class Intro(Screen):
    pass
class Lieferant(Screen):
    pass

class CWApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Intro(name='Intro'))
        sm.add_widget(Lieferant(name='Lieferant'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CWApp().run()
```

Is it possible to combine them? How would you do this? 
This code is running if I just comment this line out, which adds a screen before the screen with the dropdown:

```
sm.add_widget(Intro(name='Intro'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - for this question I got the "Tumbleweed Badget" - LOL
I admit it's a very special one and makes obvious, how much I am a beginner here. So I asked another question based on the same problem and spend some effort to make it easier to understand the code and to reproduce it. This paid off! Look here for the solution if you tumble once into that kind of problem: [Is it a bug in Kivy? DropDown + ScreenManager not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044266/is-it-a-bug-in-kivy-dropdown-screenmanager-not-working-as-expected)